# Cordova / Phonegap app - change Facebook account

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, authentication

So I'm building an app using Phonegap, and will provide social login via Facebook, Google and Twitter.

When logging to one of those, it asks about permissions. Grant it, and you are logged in. Great. My problem is, if I want to connect with another account, how can I do that ? On a regular browser, I would go to Facebook, disconnect, connect the second account, and then come back to the app to connect with it. But Phonegap uses webviews, and no URL is available to get to Facebook and change user. Though, even when disconnectiong, it's impossible to connect with another account.

How could I solve that ?

Thanks ahead !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually here is the solution. Clear all the webview cookies when the user hit logout button using this plugin :

https://github.com/bez4pieci/Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin/tree/master

Answer (score 1):

Impossible. Please refer to facebook documentation here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: Actually, you aren't right, as the official documentation shows, it looks like I can ask for a total FB disconnect : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#logout

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible please implement core Facebook sdk and you will get full control over Facebook sdk singing and sign out option for iOS here is a detailed tutorial.
http://m-farhan.com/2014/03/ios-facebook-sdk-tutorial/

Comment: There is no link between IOS and the issue.